# Virtualbox: Raw linux partition not booting

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, partitioning, virtual-machine, multi-boot

I have a dual-boot laptop with Windows 7 and Ubuntu 12.04.  I am trying to boot the ubuntu partition from windows using Virtualbox. I have successfully created the .vmdk, and created the virtual machine.  However, I can't get it to boot (in Virtualbox).  All I get is a black screen with the cursor in the top left.

I wonder if I'm specifying the partitions correctly.  My Ubuntu install has 3 partitions:  \, \boot, \home.  No swap partition.  These are all in Disk 0, partitions 3,4,5 respectively.

The command I used to create the .vmdk is:

```
 VBoxManage internalcommands createrawvmdk -filename C:\Users\abalter\.virtualbox\ubuntu.vmdk -rawdisk \\.\PhysicalDrive0 -partitions 3,4,5
```

Then I create a virtual machine based on that .vmdk.

Why won't it boot?

Answer (score 2):

It's a known bug: https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/9926
This http://www.neowin.net/forum/topic/784138-howto-boot-existing-ubuntu-partition-using-virtualbox-inside-windows/ suggests creating a custom iso that bootstraps grub2 as a workaround.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by custom ISO.  Could you explain?  I've gotten it to work with a USB drive with no custom ISO.

Comment: The purpose of the custom install ISO is to include programs that put the grub2 partition inside the linux partition.

Instead, putting Linux on its own disk (for your case a USB stick), also works since the problem is with windows and linux on the same disk.

Answer (score 1):

I just did this yesterday, finally got it working using this tutorial: https://askubuntu.com/questions/78902/cannot-run-native-ubuntu-in-virtualbox-with-a-vmdk-created-using-the-createrawvm

I used ceztko's post (copied below). Note also that after I had it all working, I booted into Ubuntu *in the VM* and re-ran `update-grub`, which got rid of the extra entry in grub for Windows 7 (this is for safety's sake; if you accidentally try to boot the Win 7 partition from within a VM running on that same Windows 7 install, bad bad bad things will happen). After doing this, I essentially have 2 separate installs of grub: one on the system MBR that includes entries for Win 7 and Ubuntu, and one on the MBR of the VirtualBox .vmdk file (even though this file points to the raw Ubuntu partition, it's possible for it to have a different MBR).

ceztko's post:

> I found a perfectly working workaround. sda7 is the partition where I
>   installed linux, 5,6,7 are the native partition I want to virtualize,
>   and "ceztko" is my home :P
>
> - from the native linux, reinstall the grub to the native linux partition: `sudo-grub install --force /dev/sda7`
> - copy the partition boot sector to your home: `# dd if=/dev/sda7 of=/home/ceztko/virtualbox-native.mbr bs=512 count=1`
> - copy virtualbox-native.mbr to your windows installation
> - Reboot to Windows and from Administrator prompt: 
>     `VBoxManage internalcommands  createrawvmdk -filename C:\users\ceztko\ubuntu.vmdk -rawdisk \\.\PhysicalDrive0 -partitions 5,6,7 -mbr c:\users\ceztko\Dropbox\resources\virtualbox-native.mbr`
> - Run VirtualBox and assign the new virtual drive to the virtual
>     machine.
> - Enjoy!
>
> This may be a bug in Virtualbox. But better I guess is a bug in grub,
>   confused by the non-accessible Windows partitions when installed as
>   mbr in the boot disk.

Edit: I should mention that Hemlock was pretty close - the problem is indeed that the .vmdk file pointing to the raw partition doesn't include a valid bootloader/boot sector. The first step in cetzko's post has you install grub to the MBR *of the partition*, and then make a copy of that MBR to add in to the .vmdk file. Normally grub is installed to the MBR of the entire hard drive.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the boot sector. You probably aren't including it in the available partitions of your raw disk.

I accomplished something similar this way:

1. Create a virtual drive as you normally would.
2. Create the raw disk you have described
3. Install to the virtual drive
4. Mount `/` on the virtual drive and `/home` on your raw disk
5. *Make sure that the virtual drive is set as the boot disk*. This is where I had problems.
6. Enjoy

Comment: Thanks Hemlock, but that's not quite the solution I'm looking for.  That would allow me to share the /home directory, but not all installed apps etc.  More importantly, I want to be in the same environment regardless of whether I booting into the linux partition or accessing it through VB from Windows.

Comment: _You'll never be in the same environment_; the virtualization doesn't have the same hardware.

Comment: This cannot be true.  The method I used is from the Virtualbox documentation.  Others seem to have gotten it to work.  Also, I've successfully done what I want with a USB drive:  i.e. installed ubuntu, and can boot natively from the USB drive or through virtualbox in Windows 7.